# Maven using wrong dependency version

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

The dependency version I want to use is 4.5.0 as specified in my **pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
  <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
  <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I run `mvn clean install -DskipTest=true`. Maven will download and use version 4.2.2.

[libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmK15.png)

I tried searching in the entire project thinking maybe there are other files(*in this case pom.xml*) that specify the version to 4.2.2 but found nothing.

Has anybody encountered this issue before? I'm new to Java and I can't think of any other reason as to why this is happening.

Comment: hey .. try the command 'maven dependency:tree'. This way you will know if some other dependency in your project is the root cause for this issue. If you find 4.2.2 in the dependency tree, then in pom.xml exclude that version

Comment: @Sarjit The `.m2` folder only holds a cache of all downloaded versions. There might be multiple versions of one library present in `.m2`. This is intended behaviour.

Comment: Delete the files inside .m2 folder and then run `mvn -U clean install`

Comment: I' ve just tried adding the above dependencies and maven correctly download 4.5.0 version. Take a look if you got other dependencies that refer to the wrong version. It' s also perfectly safe to delete your whole .m2 directory and then rebuild your project (**In this case all of your project will need to download their dependencies again of course**)

Comment: @Sarjit I checked m2 folder and there exist version 4.5.0 and 4.2.2. However, my project will choose the latter.

Comment: Show the whole pom.xml.

Comment: Please show the full pom file otherwise it's impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: maven dependency:tree cmd output or In eclipse there's a tab on the POM file editor labeled "Dependency Hierarchy" check for transitive dependency

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output of `mvn dependency:list`. It will list you all dependencies of the project with their respective versions.

This is the truth. If your Eclipse or IntelliJ or whatever list something else, they are most certainly wrong/outdated.